# Adding an access policy to a Key Vault which is in another resource group

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I am trying to add access policy to an existing key vault which belongs to a different resource group. There was a suggestion from stackoverflow but I have authorization issue on implementing write.  .
[How to add Access Policy to a Keyvault in different Resource Group through ARM Templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58660134/how-to-add-access-policy-to-a-keyvault-in-different-resource-group-through-arm-t)

I am trying a different way as below. I am adding the resource group in the name. But I am getting "different segment length" error

```
"resources": [
     {
      "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
      "name": "[concat("/",parameters('resourceGroupName'),"/",parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
      "properties": {
        "accessPolicies": [
          {
            "tenantId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionAppName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').tenantId]",
            "objectId": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',  variables('functionAppName'), '/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/Identities/default'), '2015-08-31-PREVIEW').principalId]",
            "permissions": {
            "secrets": [
                    "get",
                    "list"
                ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
```

Is this even possible to add the resource group in the name?

Comment: Can you please add more information about how you are trying to achieve this, e.g. via the Azure CLI or an ARM Deploy Task in Azure DevOps? What you are wanting to do is technically possible, it is just a matter of defining your current set up so that someone can provide the relevant advice. If you have not already, I would suggest looking at targeting the deployment at the subscription level, rather than resource group level. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-to-subscription?tabs=azure-cli.

Comment: @MattStannett It is thru ARM Deploy Task in Octopus.

Comment: Does it work when you use the Azure portal? If it does then you know it's not an authorization issue.

Comment: Can you try this once "[concat(parameters('resourceGroupName'),"/",parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]" as it is giving segment length error.

Comment: Failing @JagratiModi's suggestion and assuming that you're using the Octopus task outlined [here](https://octopus.com/docs/runbooks/runbook-examples/azure/resource-groups), it looks like it's tied to a Resource Group. You could either: hardcode the resource id of the vault in your ARM template (I wouldn't recommend it) or use the [Run An Azure PowerShell Script task](https://octopus.com/docs/deployments/custom-scripts/azure-powershell-scripts) along with a [subscription deployment scope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deploy-powershell). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using resources in another resource group, you need to **change the deployment scope to Subscription**.

As suggested by [Matt Stannett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5209435/matt-stannett), you can either use **Azure CLI or PowerShell script task** in Octopus to get the Resource ID of your key vault